# TypeError: integer argument expected, got float python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, opencv3.0

I am using the following code to detecion pattern. Why does it throw a TypeError?

```
# loop over the contours
```

for c in cnts:

```
# compute the center of the contour
M = cv2.moments(c)

    cX = (M["m10"] / (M["m00"] + 1e-7))
cY = (M["m01"] / (M["m00"] + 1e-7))

# draw the contour and center of the shape on the image
cv2.drawContours(frame1, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.circle(frame1, (cX, cY), 7, (255, 255, 255), -1)
cv2.putText(frame1, "center", (cX - 20, cY - 20),
    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2)
```

This massage error

```
    cv2.circle(frame1, (cX, cY), 7, (255, 255, 255), -1)
```

TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

Comment: opencv wants [circle center](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/drawing_functions.html) to have integer coordinates

Comment: I imitate the program people, on his program can. but I do not.
I think the above program is appropriate

Answer (score 3):

`(cX, cY)` is an OpenCV point. It represents *x-y* coordinates, in other words a pixel position. If the function you are calling says it expects an integer there, then it expects an integer. Whatever you think it should expect.

`cv2.moments()` returns a dictionary of 10 floats. If you want to use the values that it returns as coordinate points then you will need to convert them to integers somehow.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your division gives you a float value:

```
cX = (M["m10"] // (M["m00"] + 1e-7))
cY = (M["m01"] // (M["m00"] + 1e-7))
```

This will solve your problem.